# Как осуществить перенос объекта из одного состояния/формы в другое?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, теория

Хочу сделать подобное готовке еды в игре "Overcooked". Где ты готовишь разнообразные блюда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу уловить идею как она реализуется или с чего начать. Ты берёшь объект (овощ), взаимодействуешь с необходимыми "изменителями" (нарезка, готовка). По окончанию процесса - подменяешь модель и идёшь дальше?

Comment: Ну да, например так. А что вас смущает в этом подходе?

Comment: Вы художник, как сделаете так и будет

Answer (score 0):

(Не часто отвечаю на вопросы, но этот немного знаком)

В данном случае я бы мог порекомендовать немного иной подход, берутся уже готовые модели фрукта в нарезном виде, и посредством анимации имитируется нарезка а по факту, идёт обман игрока, ибо визуально если все соединить то будет к примеру тот же огурец. Фишка такого похода что можно управлять процессом "нарезки" или отделения по кусочку он общей кучи, при помощи Анимации и встроенных методов взаимодействия с ней.

Но как альтернатива,да можно сделать все через разрушаемость объектов (ну имитировать его методом подмены), вот пример (не лучший но так, для понимания)

-(ссылка): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7s-RaV2wikI

Надеюсь чем то помог, будут вопросы то задавайте.